# Google maps api not working with variables

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I believe it is passing the variable as a string when using:

> document.getElementById("lblLatitude")

When you hardcode the coordinates it works perfectly fine. When using a variables it just brings back a gray-out box without the google maps loading. Is there a reason why these variables will not work?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function initMap() {

        // Declare
        var Latitude = document.getElementById("lblLatitude");
        var Longitude = document.getElementById("lblLongitude");

        // Map options
        var options = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: { lat: Latitude, lng: Longitude }
        }

        // New map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
    }
```

Comment: What type of elements are `lblLatitude` and `lblLongitude`?

Comment: Before `// Map options` add a `console.log(Latitude, Longitude)`. Are there any values there?

Comment: @DanielGeffen I'm using a Label control to bind it from the database. In the database, I have it as a nvarchar(20).

Comment: Try this quick fix: `var Latitude = document.getElementById("lblLatitude") * 1;`

Comment: @besciualex the values were null

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a HTML `label` control, you can fix this issue by calling `textContent` on the DOM elements like:

```
var Latitude = document.getElementById("<%=lblLatitude.ClientID%>").textContent || 0;
var Longitude = document.getElementById("<%=lblLongitude.ClientID%>").textContent || 0;
```

Or,

```
var Latitude = document.querySelector("[id$='lblLatitude']").textContent || 0;
var Longitude = document.querySelector("[id$='lblLongitude']").textContent || 0;
```

and then use it like:

```
// Map options
var options = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: { lat: +Latitude, lng: +Longitude }
}
```

Right now you are passing dom nodes to `lat` & `lng` but they expect a number instead.

Demo using label:

```js
var Latitude = document.getElementById("lblLatitude").textContent || 0;
var Longitude = document.getElementById("lblLongitude").textContent || 0;
console.log( Latitude, Longitude )
```

```html
<label id="lblLatitude">-34.397</label><br>
<label id="lblLongitude">150.644</label>
```

Comment: I read the comments just now. Please try the updated code as you are using simple `label` which does not have a `value` prop.

Comment: When I change from an Asp.net Label to Html label it works in this case scenario. I was doing it with Asp.net control.

Comment: Ok, You can use `document.getElementById("<%=lblLatitude.ClientID%>")` if `document.getElementById("lblLatitude")` didn't work with asp label, as in asp.net ids are updated as per master page and stuff.